# Add Pinpoint to Cognito which are in different regions

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint

I have Cognito user pool in a region(say us-east-1) and Pinpoint in a different region(say us-east-2). When tried to add Pinpoint to the cognito pool in console(go to cognito->manage user pool->click analytics in the left pane), there was no option being displayed for pinpoint since it is in different region. Is there any way that I can connect these two(Cannot implement sign-in sign-up in front end as we are already using AWS login/sign-up). It would be helpful if you could suggest a way I can do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time (**August 30th 2020**) of writing this answer, **Amazon Pinpoint** service is not yet supported in Ohio us-east-2

- This explains why you won't be able to see any pinpoint project in the dropdown menu of Cognito userpool console (General settings-> Analytics in the left pane)

Looking at the [**Amazon Pinpoint documentation**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-pinpoint-integration.html) it states:

> In regions where Pinpoint is not available, Cognito UserPools only supports sending events to Amazon Pinpoint projects in us-east-1. In regions where Pinpoint is available, Cognito User Pools will support sending events to Amazon Pinpoint projects within that same region.

This means that: *For example if you have a **Cognito UserPool** in **eu-west-1** then you can use a Pinpoint project in **eu-west-1** (a region where Pinpoint is not supported) however if your Cognito UserPool is in **us-east-2** (a region where Pinpoint is not supported) then you'll need to use a Pinpoint project in **us-east-1** in-order to capture events.*

Sample illustration below:

[image]

Comment: I don't have any Analytics section in the general settings of a user pool. Might be because of some services being unavailable in the region (eu-west-3). So I guess I cannot connect my user pool to pinpoint